# Why this code print 20 undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, return, iteration, undefined

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/8ejhR/) :

```
var coordinateTratte = {
        "1522-nord": [
             {"Distanza": 0, "Lat": 45.02915, "Lng": 7.606131667},            
             {"Distanza": 0.1, "Lat": 45.02805167, "Lng": 7.605818333}
        ]
    };

for (var key in coordinateTratte) {
    var obj = coordinateTratte[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {  
        console.log(obj[prop].Lat);
    }
}
​
```

Why 20 undefined?

Comment: yes, works: http://jsfiddle.net/8ejhR/1/

Comment: You have MooTools loaded and as others show, you are not properly iterating the Array. When you use jsFiddle, it's best to first set the proper settings on the left, like choosing `No-Library (pure JS)` from the menu.

Comment: Is it so a stupid question? -3? Lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"1522-nord"` is an array through which you were traversing with a for-in. Do not use a for-in on arrays. Use a regular loop:

```
for (var key in coordinateTratte) {
    var obj = coordinateTratte[key];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { // <--
        console.log(obj[i].Lat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var coordinateTratte = {"1522-nord":[{"Distanza":0,"Lat":45.02915,"Lng":7.606131667},{"Distanza":0.1,"Lat":45.02805167,"Lng":7.605818333}]};

for (var key in coordinateTratte) {
    var obj = coordinateTratte[key];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {  
        console.log(obj[i].Lat);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdgnJ/

Answer (score 1):

@user1689607's comment seems to me to be the answer. When you select `no lib (pure JS)`, your code doesn't log any `undefined` values. The thing is: libs often fiddle with the prototypes of native types. The most notorious lib to do so is `prototype.js` (the clue is in the name). The *"magic property"* of a regular, unaltered `Array` object, for example is not enumerable (ie: doesn't show up in a `for...in` loop of an array). When you start adding your own properties and methods, however, chances are that they *will* show up. Since the `Array` is derived from the `Object` prototype, any alterations to that prototype might show up, too.

The long and short of it is: *never*, **ever** use `for...in` on an array. If you do use `for...in` (on an object), always check if whatever property you're processing is set directly on that object, and isn't coming from the prototype:

```
for (var prop in someObject)
{
    if (someObject.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

As far as arrays is concerned: `for(var i=0;i<theArray.length;i++)` should help you steer clear of most issues (keep in mind that arrays are sparse in JS):

```
var normalArray = [1,2];
var sparseArray = [1,2,3,4];
delete sparseArray[2];//will log [1,2,undefined,4]
for (var i=0;i<sparseArray.length;i++)
{
    if (i < normalArray.length)
    {
        console.log(normalArray[i]);
    }
    console.log(sparseArray[i]);//will log 1 - 2 - undefined - 4
    if (sparseArray.hasOwnProperty(i))
    {
        console.log(sparseArray[i]);//logs 1 - 2 - 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for (var key in coordinateTratte) {
    var obj = coordinateTratte[key];
    for (var prop in obj) {  
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            console.log(obj[prop].Lat);
    }
}
```

You iterate over all Array properties. Even if they come from its prototype.

Comment: +1 :-] Also, you could use http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm in order to get a clear look of your structure and see when you should loop trough object and when array.

Comment: -1 Don't use for in on arrays, even if it works.

Comment: Btw. for arrays it's better to use simple `for` loop or `forEach` method (if your code doesn't have to run on old IE - [check browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

Comment: @David : "Don't use for in on arrays, even if it works." Why? Just curious...

Comment: @markzzz It's verbose, unreadable, and you need to use the `.hasOwnProperty` method. Also, if beginners see this, they might imitate it incorrectly in their own programs.